# What is className="mt-5" in reactstrap or in bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4, reactstrap

What role does "mt-5" does when we use it as a class name in reactstrap or bootstrap?

Comment: Is [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) what you're looking for?

Comment: it means `margin-top` and the bootstrap team has given it a value of `3rem`

Answer (score 1):

It is just a shortcut for giving an element some margin.`mt-5` is margin top 5. there is mt-0-5 available for different spaces.

You can also check the [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/) for more information.